# Derive row from unboound DataGridVew

Tags: datagridview, row

I have a datagridview with 12 columns. When I try to derive a new DataGridViewRow from DataGridView using the code below, the row.Cells count is 0.

Is possible to derive a new row from the DataGridView so I don't have to add the columns programmatically. I already have the columns designed, I don't want to have manually add them again for each row.

Thanks,
Susan

```
        For Each rowSQL As MyDataSet.GetStudentRow In Me._CurrentOrder.GetStudents.Rows
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Me.dgDetails.RowTemplate

        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            Dim aa As String = cell.Value.ToString
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim row As New DataGridViewRow
row.CreateCells(Me.dgDetails)
```